# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45 seconds

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import com.performance.script.script1;
import com.performance.script.script2;
import com.performance.script.script3;
import com.support.*;

    public class ThreadsRunnable{
        static GetSessionID gsi = new GetSessionID();
        static int threadUsers=30;
        static Thread thr2;

        public void testmain() throws InterruptedException{

    //            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                  for (int i=1; i<=threadUsers; i++) {
                    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
    //                    latch.await();
                          script1 s1 = new script1();
                          s1.setUp();
                          s1.testscript1();
                          cnq.tearDown();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ie) { } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                      }
                    };
                    new Thread(runner, "TestThread"+i).start();
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                  }
                  // all threads are waiting on the latch.
    //            latch.countDown();// release the latch
```

// all threads are now running concurrently.
                    }
            public static void main(String arg[]) throws InterruptedException{
                ThreadsRunnable tr = new ThreadsRunnable();
                tr.testmain();
            }
        }

Below is the code which I run to find if the port 7054 is free and
it always display as free on console. However, when i pass this port
to run firefox it gives error, port binding can anyone help me on
this. Thanks

```
 package GroboUtils;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.DatagramSocket;
 import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;

 /**
  * * Finds an available port on localhost.
  */
 public class PortFinder {

 // the ports below 1024 are system ports   private final int
 MIN_PORT_NUMBER  = 7054;

 // the ports above 49151 are dynamic and/or private    private final
 int MAX_PORT_NUMBER = 49151;

 /**
 * * Finds a free port between * {@link #MIN_PORT_NUMBER} and
 * {@link #MAX_PORT_NUMBER}. * * @return a free port * @throw
 * RuntimeException if a port could not be found
 */
 public int
        findFreePort() {
    for (int i = MIN_PORT_NUMBER; i
            <= MAX_PORT_NUMBER; i++) {
        if (available(i)) {
            //        System.out.println("Free Port: "+i);
            return i;
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not find an available port between"
            + MIN_PORT_NUMBER + " and " + MAX_PORT_NUMBER);
 }

 /**
 * * Returns true if the specified port is available on this host. * *
 * @param port the port to check * @return true if the port is available,
 * false otherwise
 */
 private boolean
        available(final int port) {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    DatagramSocket dataSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        dataSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        dataSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        return true;
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (dataSocket != null) {
            dataSocket.close();
        }
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                // can never happen
            }
        }
    }
 }

 public void portReuse() {
    try {
        ServerSocket socket1 = new ServerSocket();
        ServerSocket socket2 = new ServerSocket();
        ServerSocket socket3 = new ServerSocket();
        int port = 7054;

        socket2.setReuseAddress(true);
        socket2.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", port));

        Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

 public static void main(String agr[]) {
    PortFinder pf = new PortFinder();
    pf.findFreePort();
 }

}
```

Comment: sorry for in-formatted code above...

Comment: Unless this is some esoteric formatting convention I've not heard of, you might want to think about using your IDE's pretty-format features to fix that second code snippet of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add the below host entry to your hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

It worked for me

Comment: Can you please elaborate why this works?